# High Availability on Azure database for Postgres

Tags: azure, azure-postgresql

As per  document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-high-availability

for any failure/service down , automatically new service  will deployed and re attach the storage to new server.

new service with same hostname/ip address or different.if it is different,how can we achieve same hostname because we can't change the connection string in application

Comment: you do not need to change anything, as and when the service recovers it will be on the same hostname and you will use the same connection string. Just write your code with the functionality to avoid transient connection failures. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-connectivity

Comment: It is for Transient connection issue.. but in document they Mentioned  "the database server goes down unexpectedly, a new database server is automatically provisioned in seconds. The remote storage is automatically attached to the new database server". when i try to test this scenario, new server is not deploying.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is answered in the document you linked.

> Applications using the PostgreSQL databases need to be built in a way that they detect and retry dropped connections and failed transactions. **When the application retries, the Gateway transparently redirects the connection to the newly created database server.**

Comment: 1)Gateway mechanism provided by  Azure or  have to configure the in application?    2)we are tested by stoping the service,but new service not deployed.

Comment: The gateway is - much like the remote storage - a component included in Azure's PostgreSQL Server. Have you even read und understood the document you linked?